# fontspec's LetterSpace behaves differently in xetex and luatex

Tags: xetex, luatex, fontspec, small-caps, letterspacing

In `xetex`, activating the `LetterSpace` option for small caps adds extra space when a small caps letter is directly followed by a lowercase latter, but has no effect when a lower case letter is directly followed by small caps.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}[%
    SmallCapsFeatures = {LetterSpace = 50}]

\begin{document}
\textsc{uio}

\textsc{u}i\textsc{o}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In `luatex`, on the other hand, no extra space is added either before or after a lower case letter adjacent to small caps:

[image]

Why does it behave differently in `xetex` and `luatex`, and who's doing the "right thing" here?

Comment: I guess that LuaTeX is going the right way here: letterspacing is used to space out caps and small caps for readability issues, not to make them feel cramped. Being that I cannot envision a word with small caps and lowercase and small caps again (Except in logos), I feel that the extra requirement for small caps space is not applicable here. Also I feel it has more to do with `fontspec` inner workings than one or the other engines

Comment: @Moriambar Words mixing upper and lower case letters have become very common in abbreviations, especially in Europe, where it's been a fad for years (to my distaste). There's no consensus whether the upper case letters should be written with small caps (a classic case is the German abbreviation "GmbH").

Comment: I come from Europe too and I don't find common *small caps*  with *lowercase* perhaps full caps are best suited? I think small caps give the best when typesetting all-caps words amongst the text, ie `UK`, or `WWF`; I feel that small caps with lowercase in acronyms such as `GmbH` would feel weird.

Answer (score 2):

You should add `\nocorr`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}[ 
  SmallCapsFeatures = {LetterSpace = 50},
]

\begin{document}

\textsc{uio}

\textsc{u}i\textsc{o}

\textsc{u\nocorr}i\textsc{o}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: does this mean that `luatex` has the choice to put a `nocorr` at the end of `\textsc`?

Comment: So you think `xetex` is doing the wrong thing here? And, is `\nocorr` a hack here? Isn't `\nocorr` for suppressing italic correction?

Comment: @Sverre I don't know whether it's right or wrong, but the problem is apparently the addition of a kern, without `\nocorr`.